# how can I make a symbolic link to python3 created by venv on OS X?

Tags: macos, matplotlib, pycharm, symlink, python-venv

Matplotlib now requires python to be installed as a framework to use it in interactive mode ([Working with Matplotlib on OSX](https://matplotlib.org/faq/osx_framework.html)), which I do as:

```
python -m venv my-virtualenv
source my-virtualenv/bin/activate
```

This works fine. For example, if I do:

```
my-virtualenv> pip3 install tensorflow
```

in this new environment it builds tensorflow fine and I can import it fine when I enter the python3 shell within my-virtualenv. However, when I create a symbolic link:

```
ln -s my-virtualenv/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python36x
```

and then enter the python36x shell tensorflow e.g. is not available. I've tried

```
python -m venv --copies my-virtualenv
```

as well to no avail. How can I create a functional symbolic link?

Comment: Why are you creating that symbolic link? What did you expect it to achieve? Are you trying to use a virtualenv without activating it?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using Pycharm. If I set up the virtual environment as stated above and point the interpreter for Pycharm to the one in the virtual environment it works - it effectively activates the environment. But if I point it to a symbolic link of the interpreter it fails. If I use virtualenv (instead of venv) to set up the virtual environment the symbolic link works but then Matplotlib fails because it now requires the python to be in a framework (which venv creates).

Answer (score 4):

Python3's venv creates a link to the virtual environment's bin/python instead of copying the file like virtualenv.  Python2's loader would follow links until the actual python executable was located, then use that directory to locate the libraries (../lib/).  Python3's loader does not follow the links, but uses the directory of the python (link or not) to locate the libraries.

You can use an alias instead of a link:

```
alias python36e=my-virtualenv/bin/python3
```

It's not on the path but is directly accessible.

A better solution would be putting a wrapper script on your path.

```
# cat /usr/local/bin/python36x
myprog=my-virtualenv/bin/python3

exec "${myprog}" "$@"
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

OK, Pycharm actually has its own way of dealing with this: see [how to set the interpreter to use across multiple platforms](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html). Pycharm is very nice!